# Contour on a pcolor image with shading flat

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour

I am trying to fit a contour over a `pcolor` image. I am using the `'shading flat'` feature of `pcolor` which I have to keep with and since I do not have a very high resolution dataset the pixels are clearly distinctive as expected. However, when I use the `contour(x,y,z)` command it will not overlay my given contour limits nicely and it looks like it follows the interpolated pattern of the `pcolor` command (`'shading interp'`).

Does anybody know how to get a well fitting contour over a `pcolor` with `'shading flat'`?

My code:

```
h_fig1 = figure(1);
pcolor(x,y,double(data.vhh));
shading flat;
hold on
[co cvhh] = contour(x,y,double(data.vhh),[0 20],'k','LineWidth',1);
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you know about [**`contourf`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html)?